# JBoss ESB pipeline interceptors

Tags: jboss, esb, interceptor, jboss6.x

I am new to JBoss ESB and I am trying to intercept and handle all messages that happen on my application server.

I found that **pipeline interceptors** are what I am looking for. However, I am unable to make them work. Could you direct me to any tutorial concerning this problematigue? I tried documentation for JBoss ESB but this section is very vague. Is there any working sample with pipeline interceptors? I have not found any...

Here is what I have tried:

```
import org.jboss.soa.esb.helpers.ConfigTree;
import org.jboss.soa.esb.listeners.message.PipelineInterceptor;
import org.jboss.soa.esb.message.Message;

public class Interceptor implements PipelineInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Message msg, ConfigTree arg1) {
        System.out.println("Intercepted" + msg.getContext());

    }

}
```

I programmed this very simple class and converted it into a .jar file and placed it in the root directory of my project. I also copied jbossesb-properties.xml next to it and uncommented the interceptors section. What else should I do? Where do I specify the path to my interceptor class?

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a day of trying everything possible, I think I have solved it. You have to place the .jar file with Interceptor somewhere in the path of ESB (the best way is probably to the folder with deployed ESB in AS) and specify path to it in jbossesb-properties.xml file...